# We installed Nodejs 8 on ubuntu 16.04. As a result npm was also installed. Later when we enter npm we are getting the error URIError: URI malformed

Tags: node.js

We installed Nodejs 8 in ubuntu 16.04. As a result npm was also installed. Later when we enter npm we are getting the below error. Please help!!!!

```
URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
    at Url.parse (url.js:334:19)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:144:13)
    at Object.validateUrl [as validate] 
    (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:172:13)
    at validate (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:221:24)
    at validate (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:187:11)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:104:12
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:70:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:61
      throw new Error('npm.load() required')
      ^

Error: npm.load() required
    at Object.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:61:13)
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:18)
    at process.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:448:27)
```

Comment: Delete the file .npmrc from C:\Users\username and run the command again.Hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: Its in ubuntu linx box not windows.